# How to get Min in C# Linq with join and group by?

Tags: c#, linq, join, group-by, min

I want to build a Linq query for below scenario:

Table 1

```
PriceId
ProductId
ProductPrice 
ProductHeight
ProductWeight
ProductType
```

Table 2

```
ProductId
ProductName
```

Task:
Select the cheapest prices and names for products where:

- productHeight = 5
- productWeight = 10
- productTypes: "abc", "xyz"

The end expected result is a list of objects like this:

```
ProductId
ProductName
TheCheapestPrice(the cheapest ProductPrice)
```

I created a SQL query to get this info, however I have a problem with 
writing it in LINQ.

SQL query:

```
SELECT
    t1.ProductId,
    t2.ProductName,
    MIN(t1.ProductPrice) AS TheCheapestPrice
FROM
    Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ProductId = t2.ProductId
WHERE
    t1.ProductHeight = 5
    AND
    t1.ProductWeight = 10
    AND
    t1.ProductType IN ('abc', 'xyz')
GROUP BY
    t1.ProductId,
    t2.ProductName
```

Can you please, help me to achieve the same result in LINQ?

So far I created such a LINQ, however I have a problem with getting minimum price:

```
from t1 in Table1
where
    productTypes.Contains(t1.ProductType)
    &&
    t1.ProductHeight == 5
    &&
    t1.ProductWeight == 10 
join t2 in Table2 on t1.ProductId equals t2.ProductId
group new { t1.ProductId, t2.ProductName }
by new { t1.ProductId, t2.ProductName } into topPrices
select new 
{
    ProductId = topPrices.Key.ProductId,
    ProductName = topPrices.Key.ProductName,
    TheCheapestPrice = ???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to adjust your group to return the `t1` record since you want to access its `ProductPrice` property:

```
group t1 by new { t1.ProductId, t2.ProductName } into topPrices
```

Then all you need is to perform the `Min` on the `topPrices` group, like this:

```
TheCheapestPrice = topPrices.Min(t => t.ProductPrice)
```

[Link to working fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q3rDEf)

HTH

Comment: This isn't the same as the working SQL query OP posted. Note that OP is grouping on a different field than they are filtering on.

Comment: @TomK see updated answer. Once you adjust your group to return the entire `t1` record you can access its price property and perform the `Min` on it.

Comment: @Flater not sure what you mean, it is returning multiple prices, lowest prices on each group. See working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/q3rDEf

Comment: @jcruz Thank you, your answer solves my problem. Do you know any place where I can read why this approach works?

Comment: @TomK In short, when doing a `group` in Linq you specify the projection of the grouped records. There are many resources online, here is one with many examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results